# How to pass raw data from controller into javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, web2py

I want to pass certain `data` to a javascript function `my_function(data)` embedded in my view.

In the controller I do this:

```
data = "[{value: 1, color: '#FF0000'},{value: 1, color: '#FF0000'} ]"
```

That is the way the data has to come into the function. I came a long way using this:

```
my_function({{ =XML(response.json(data)) }}
```

It works up to this point, but the data ends up like this:

```
"[{value: 1, color: '#FF0000'},{value: 1, color: '#FF0000'} ]"
```

but I kneed it like this - without the quotes around `[...]`:

```
[{value: 1, color: '#FF0000'},{value: 1, color: '#FF0000'} ]
```

How do I manage to do so?

Comment: After all I have to say that the whole idea was wrong. The solution was to define a small helper function `build_js(data)` to return a HTML Script Tag. The data needed is passed to the function. Thanks @Anthony anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is already JSON, so no need for `response.json` -- just do:

```
my_function({{=XML(data)}})
```

Alternatively, you can make `data` a Python object and use `response.json` to convert it to JSON:

```
data = [{'value': 1, 'color': '#FF0000'}, {'value': 1, 'color': '#FF0000'}]
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped. But for it to work I had also to do this: "my_function(my_data = {{=XML(data)}})"

Comment: Hmm, Javascript generally doesn't require parameter names. What does the function definition look like?

Comment: See my comment below the question, in the end the whole idea was wrong. For the JS: I tried to implement `chart.js` (chartjs.org)